# Synchronous XMLHttpRequest to download a video

Tags: javascript, ajax, blob

I would like to download completely a mp4 video from an Ajax request in order to render it later.

With an asynchronous request, it works correctly :

```
const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', myVideoUrl, true);
req.responseType = 'blob';
req.onload = function() {
  renderVideo(URL.createObjectURL(this.response));
};
```

But I would prefer to do it synchronously in order to block the rendering until the video is downloaded. I tried this way, but it doesn't work...

```
const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', myVideoUrl, false);
req.send(null);
const blob = new Blob([req.responseText], { type: 'video/mp4' });
renderVideo(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
```

I think the problem comes from the binary data and the conversion I tried from responseText to objectUrl...

Any idea to resolve that ?

Comment: Blocking the rendering is a horrible idea.